# keras sequental method equivalent in numpy

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

What is the equilavent of tensorflow keras's sequential model in numpy?
How can I find that?

```
# define model
model = Sequential()
```

this page has no hints how it works in detail

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Sequential

Comment: numpy is not a deep learning library and does not have anything like that.

Comment: yes itt doesnt, but math has, so i need this maths, i think sequential() its nothing more than a wrapper or init function.

Comment: It makes much sense if there are some layers otherwise it is nothing but a Sequential Object as Sequential is a class

Comment: how can we see or translate it to numpy maths thats my question